# Set of recurring decimals has an supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a function from the set of natural numbers to the set of real numbers. 
$$f(x) = (10^x-1)/(3*10^{x-1})$$

This generates the set ${3, 3.3, 3.33, 3.333, 3.3333, ....}$

Completeness theorem in real analysis states that for every non-empty set of real numbers that is bounded above, supremum exists.

This set has many upper bounds, one of which is 3.4.

But i can't understand how to find supremum.

for example if the supremum is 
$$3.33...34$$ 
Another real,

$$3.33...334$$
is smaller than it and still an upper bound.

So i want to ask, where am i wrong?

Sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: The supremum is $10/3$. It's clear that every element of the set is strictly smaller than $10/3$, but there are elements which are within any desired $\epsilon$ of $10/3$. Another way to see this: any monotonically increasing sequence which is bounded above, converges to some limit $L$, and $L$ is the supremum of the set of sequence values. In this case, the sequence converges to $L = 10/3$.

Comment: your confusion might be about the difference between supremum and maximum. every bounded sequence has a supremum, but it may not contain its maximum. in this case, $10/3$ is the supremum, but not the maximum, since it never reaches $10/3$

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, the values of the sequence
$$f(n) = \frac{10^n - 1}{3\cdot 10^{n-1}}$$
are $3, 3.3, 3.33, 3.333, \ldots$. From this we see that $f(n)$ is strictly increasing. We can also prove this formally by observing that for all $n \in \mathbb N$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} &= \left(\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{3\cdot 10^{n}}\right)\left(\frac{3\cdot 10^{n-1}}{10^{n}-1}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{10^{n}-1}\right)\\
&= \frac{10^{n+1} - 1}{10^{n+1}-10} \\
&> 1
\end{aligned}$$
and therefore $f(n+1) > f(n)$.

Consequently, the supremum of the set $\{f(n) \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is the limit of the sequence, which is
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{10^n - 1}{3\cdot 10^{n-1}}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{10^{n}}{3\cdot 10^{n-1}}\right) - \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{3\cdot 10^{n-1}}\right) \\
&= \frac{10}{3} + 0 \\
&= \frac{10}{3}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

The supremum is $10/3$.

First note that $10/3 - f(n) = 0.0 \dots 0 \bar{3}$ where there are $n-1$ zeros after the decimal.

Proof that it is an upperbound: note that for each $x$ in the set of values,  we have $10/3 - x > 0$ by the above.

Furthermore, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, find $N$ such that $\varepsilon > 10^{-N}$. Then $10/3 - f(N+1) < \varepsilon$, that is $10/3 - \varepsilon < f(N+1)$. This last statement tells us that there cannot be a smaller upper bound than $10/3$.